# Permutation and combinations no of 6 digit numbers

Tags: permutations, combinations

Number of six digit numbers which have 3 digits even & 3 digits odd , if each digit is to be used atmost once is.

The answer I am getting is correct but I am not sure whether my solution is correct. Is my solution correct?

My solution:
Selecting 3 odd digits from 1,3,5,7,9 and 3 even digits from 0,2,4,6,8 then arranging them. Now removing those cases in which 0 is at 1st place by selecting 0 and 2 other even numbers and then selecting 3 odd numbers and finally arranging the five digits except 0 keeping 0 at first place.

[(nCr(5,3))(nCr(5,3))(6!)]-[(nCr(1,1))(nCr(4,2))(nCr(5,3))(5!)]=64800

Comment: You are absolutely right

Comment: @AshwaniSharmaAdv thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how the last line evaluates to $64800$, it's $57600$. However, $64800$ is the correct answer. I've giving the calculations below.

First calculate all possible combinations of $3$ *odd* digits and $3$ *even* digits, without using a digit more than once. This includes the cases which start with $0$.
$$\binom{6}{3}\times\bigg\{\binom{5}{3}\times3!\bigg\}\times\bigg\{\binom{5}{3}\times3!\bigg\}=72000$$
Now calculate the number of such numbers beginning with $0$.
$$\binom{5}{3}\times\bigg\{\binom{5}{3}\times3!\bigg\}\times\bigg\{\binom{4}{2}\times2!\bigg\}=7200$$
Subtracting you get the total number of *six-digited* numbers with $3$ *even* and $3$ *odd* digits as $64800$.

Comment: With 0 case why you write (6 3) before?

Comment: For the *zero-case*, I'm not writing $\binom{6}{3}$. It's $\binom{5}{3}$. Since $0$ is already fixed at the beginning, that leaves me with $5$ places to fill up, $3$ with *odd* digits and $2$ with *even* digits. How many ways to choose $3$ places for the *odd* digits? $\binom{5}{3}$. The rest $2$ places are automatically given to the *even* digits. Alternatively, you can choose the number of ways to place the *even* digits, which will be $\binom{5}{2}$. But both are same.

Comment: I wrote nCr(6,3) instead of nCr(5,3) by mistake